# showHelpMessageIfInvalid is not working

Tags: apex, lightning

I am facing an issue with`showHelpMessageIfInvalid` in lightning component here is my code.

```
 valueChangeValidation : function(component, event, helper) {
    var str = component.get('v.value');
    var number = str.trim();
    if(number.length!=9){
        alert('pass--');
        var inputComponent = component.find("fieldnumId");
        inputComponent.showHelpMessageIfInvalid('Error');
    }
},
<lightning:input value="{!v.value}" label="Name" required="true" messageWhenPatternMismatch="{!$Label.c.Invalid_Number_Length}" disabled ="{!v.isPresent}" messageWhenValueMissing="{!$Label.c.Invalid_Number_Length}" aura:id="fieldnumId" onblur="{!c.valueChangeValidation}"/>
```

here I want to show an error message if the length of the string does not equal to 9 chars, here it's throwing alert but not displaying the error message. can someone help me to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this declaratively using `min-length`, `message-when-too-short` and `pattern`

Answer (score 0):

showHelpMessageIfInvalid is meant to show an error if standard validations fail. Instead, use setCustomValidity:

```
inputComponent.setCustomValdity("Field should be 9 characters long.");
inputComponent.reportValidity();
```

You could instead also use a pattern on the field instead:

```
<lightning:input pattern="\s*\w{9}\s*" ...
```

And then use showHelpMessageIfInvalid or reportValidity.

Comment: I can't use a pattern, because I want to trim the value if it has extra spaces.